# Is Visual Studio "Git Pull" different from Git Command Line?

Tags: git, visual-studio

**Initial Condition:** I have a folder that I have just ONE file in (`scripts/app.js`)

I move that file to another directory and commit the change (`application/app.js`)

Another user has committed AND PUSHED a file to the `scripts` folder (`scripts/methods.js`)

When I go to push my change *obviously* I get an error stating I need to pull first

In Visual Studio when I pull the change there are no conflicts BUT the `methods.js` will be added to the `application` folder instead of where the user originally created it (the `scripts` folder) This occurs automatically as a Merge Commit

On Git Command Line when I run `git pull` I receive the following message:

`CONFLICT (file location): scripts/methods.js added in 351d11d4ed22f383d0a68588d186c94c81329899 inside a directory that was renamed in HEAD, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to application/methods.js.`

Why does visual studio not have a conflict if it is just running `git pull` in the background?

*Additional Notes:*

- If the folder has another file in it, none of this is a problem, the issue only occurs when all files have been moved from the folder